# How To Handle Binary Integers in an Expression Evaluator

Tags: c++

I have a function in my tokenizer of my expression evaluator that makes integers depending on the characters entered by the user in the UI portion of the program. I am now trying to handle BinaryIntegers and wondering how I can check for binary numbers. Is there a way to access how a computer reads normal integers or can I do it some other way?

```
Token::pointer_type Tokenizer::_get_number( Tokenizer::string_type::const_iterator& currentChar, Tokenizer::string_type const& expression ){

assert( isdigit( *currentChar ) && "currentChar must pointer to a digit" );

// Check for binary number
// To Do: BinaryInteger code.

// Either Integer or Real
Integer::value_type const MAX_UNSIGNED_D10 = (std::numeric_limits<Integer::value_type>::max()-10)/10;
Integer::value_type accumulator = *currentChar++ - '0';

while( currentChar != end(expression) && isdigit(*currentChar) && accumulator <= MAX_UNSIGNED_D10 )
    accumulator = accumulator * 10 + *currentChar++ - '0';

if( currentChar == end(expression) || (!isdigit( *currentChar ) && *currentChar != '.' ) )
    return make<Integer>( accumulator );

// either a real number or too big for an integer
return make<Integer>( 0 );  // replace with Real number code.
}
```

Comment: Having `assert` for simple error checking is not a good idea, as it will abort your program immediately if the assertion fails. For a tokenizer you might want to continue even after a single error (for example by skipping to a token separator and attempt to continuing parsing from there).

Comment: All numbers are represented as binary inside the computer... Binary, hexadecimal, decimal, octal, and so on are just formats to represent numbers to the humans who are reading them. To check for human input that represents a number in binary, just check for all characters to be a 1 or 0, though it would be a good idea for them to need something to tell the program that they'll be inputting binary, because 1001 could be 1001 in decimal, or 9 in binary.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just finished writing an expression parser/compiler.  In my implementation, all values are floating point, so when the tokenizer reaches a character that is not part of an operator, it calls `strtod()` on it.  If `strtod` consumes characters, it generates a literal for it, otherwise it is considered an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary number is made up of just zeros and ones.  But, there's no way to tell whether a number like `11010` means "eleven thousand ten" or "twenty-six" unless you *make* a way.  This isn't a unique problem for binary versus decimal.  It's also an issue for octal and hexadecimal too.

Over the years, there have been many ways to distinguish constants in different radices.  C/C++ uses the prefixes `0` and `0x` to identify octal and hexadecimal.  It has none for binary.  Some assemblers use punctuation-based prefixes such as `%` and `$` to distinguish binary and hex from decimals, for example, while others use suffixes.

My recommendation:  Pick a single prefix character that does not match any characters in your operator set, such as `$` or `'`, or pick a small two-character prefix such as `0b` to indicate a binary number.  Then in your code, you merely need to look for that prefix character and have a different parsing loop to handle the binary constant.  For example, if you picked `$`:

```
if (currentChar == '$')
    token = _getBinary( ++currentChar, expression );
else
    ... rest of code;
```

and then

```
Token::pointer_type Tokenizer::_get_binary( Tokenizer::string_type::const_iterator& currentChar, Tokenizer::string_type const& expression )
{
    Integer::value_type const MAX_UNSIGNED_D2 = std::numeric_limits<Integer::value_type>::max()-1)/2;
    Integer::value_type accumulator = *currentChar++ - '0';

    while ((*currentChar == '0' || *currentChar == '1') && accumulator <= MAX_UNSIGNED_D2)
         accumulator = accumulator * 2 + *currentChar++ - '0';

    return make<Integer>( accumulator );
}
```

You might want to add some error handling to that tokenizer, but you get the idea.  Now your code will recognize strings of the form `$110110` as binary constants.

Comment: How could I make it so that the prefix would be 0b? I have been trying to get that to work for the last few hours and I keep getting memory errors due to it.

Comment: Well, you need to look at the next 2 characters to ensure they are `0` and `b`, and then pass a pointer to the third character to the routine that does the binary interpretation.  To make the checks complete, you need to ensure that the remaining string is at least 3 characters long also before doing these tests.